# When using GetDrive, FreeSpace is reporting incorrect in VBSCript

Tags: vbscript

I have the code below which will get drive p(a network drive) and throw up a message box with its total & free space. Total is reporting fine but for some reason free is throwing up a completely incorrect value.

```
Set filesystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set drive = filesystemObject.GetDrive("P:")
total = round(drive.TotalSize/1024/1024/1024)
free = round(drive.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024)
MsgBox(total & " " & free) // throws up 400gb total and 34gb free
```

Free should be 1.7gb, which I have verified as being accurate on the actual server. I also checked the total free space across all drives and this total came to 25gb(across 4 drives) so I cannot see that being an impacting factor.

Does anyone know what could potentially be throwing this value off?

Edit: 
Bonds answer below is marked correct as its a secondary method of proving the code above is accurate. If you come across this problem there are several features which may impact the values that you are returned.

1) Quotas being enabled.
2) Your admins rigging free space to not be accurate. In my case the admins had been rigging the share to display a much lower free space than there actually was in an effort to make users think about what they are storing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had trouble trusting the FSO's numbers in the past, too. Have you tried using WMI?

```
Const strDrive = "P:"
intFactor = 1024 ^ 3

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_LogicalDisk where DeviceID='" & strDrive & "'")

For Each objItem in colItems 

    MsgBox "Size: " & FormatNumber(objItem.Size / intFactor)
    MsgBox "Free: " & FormatNumber(objItem.FreeSpace / intFactor)
    MsgBox "Used: " & FormatNumber((objItem.Size - objItem.FreeSpace) / intFactor)

Next
```

Comment: I get the same result, only in this situation its 33.4 as my example is rounding.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. Does it work for local volumes? Maybe it's permissions-related.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. If its a permission related, perhaps the value is not a size but an error. But if that were the case the value would not be 33,056,0.....

Comment: If it was an error, it would be reported in the `Err` object (and VBScript would throw up a message box to let you know). I'm assuming you're not using `On Error Resume Next` anywhere?

Comment: Also, do you know if the volume has quotas enabled?

Comment: The code provided is all the code there is, no error suppression. Quotas are disabled and I can not have them enabled.

Comment: Can you log in as an Admin and try running it? Or give it to an Admin to run?

Comment: Change: Quotas ARE enabled. I found out what it is after speaking with one of the admins. They rig it to make it appear as though there is only 1.7gb space free in an attempt to make users think before they store complete garbage.

Comment: Haha, sounds like something a Network Admin would do. Glad we figured it out.

Comment: It really does, does'nt it? Thanks muchly for your help.